# Arrays of cards not showing any output

Tags: java, class, variables, instance

For this, I created two java files. **Card.java** has all the *instances variables* and **Jack.java** will just run all the *card* when asked.

My Code for **Card.java** is:

```
public class Card {

    private int rank;
    private int suit;


    public Card(int rank, int suit) {

        this.rank = rank;
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public static final String[] RANKS = {
        null, "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7",
        "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    public static final String[] SUITS = {
        "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};

    public String toString() {
        String s = RANKS[this.rank] + " of " + SUITS[this.suit]; // we are actually using the instances variables to access the array elements 
        return s;

    }

    public boolean equals(Card that) { // this that could be any variables 
        return this.rank == that.rank && this.suit == that.suit;
    }
}
```

My Code for **Jack.java** is:

```
public class Jack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card small = new Card(0,1); // creates the small object
        Card card = new Card(11,1); // cretes the card object
        System.out.println(small); // prints the small class
        System.out.println(card); // prints the card class
        System.out.println(small.equals(card)); // compares small with cards

        Card[] cards = new Card[52];

        int index = 0; // to keep track
        for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) { // outer loop
            for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) { // inner loop
                cards[index] = new Card(rank, suit);
                index++;
            }
        }

        public static void printDeck(Card[] cards) {
            for (Card card : cards) {
                System.out.println(card);
            }
        }   

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cards));
    }  
}
```

All of the code works but the PrintArray doesn't work. I tried to take help from the book but I am not getting what could be the possible error. Thanks in advance. I also tried putting the void method **printDeck** in the Card.java file but then again I failed.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work - why? Can you explain the issue in detail?

Comment: The code isn't valid - you have a method `printDeck` at the code-level if you will - it needs to be a class-level item.

Answer (score 1):

### problem: your constants aren't.

Having public arrays is a bad idea. The fact that you stuck a `final` on there isn't going to fix that; arrays just can't do what you want here. I suggest you use a list instead. Try it! Write this: `Card.RANKS[1] = "10"; // hahaha I'm cheating!`

Try this instead:

```
public static final List<String> RANKS = List.of("", "Ace", "2", "3", ...);
```

or better yet, use java the way it was meant to be used. With types and names:

```
public enum Rank {
    ACE, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8, R9, R10, JACK, QUEEN, KING;
}

public class Card {
    private final Rank rank;
}
```

### problem: Your equals isn't.

The way java works is that the name of a method at runtime is a little more complicated than just the name. It is actually the name, *and* all the types of all the parameters, but without any generics that are on them, *and* the return type. So, the full name of equals is actually `equals(java.lang.Object)boolean`. Your equals method *DOES NOT* override, as it doesn't really have the same name; its name is `equals(Card)boolean`. Not the same. For any code that interacts with the equals method (such as hashmap, hashset, list.contains, and more), it won't work. You should have your equals method accept an `Object`, and check if it is a Card; if it is not, obviously, it is not equal. So, add: `if (!(that instanceof Card)) return false;`. If card isn't final, the better check is `if (that == null || that.getClass() != Card.class) return false;` for somewhat complicated reasons.

It's a great idea to add `@Override` to any method you think should override. This does nothing, unless your method doesn't actually override anything, in which case it causes the compiler to tell you about this: Hey, buddy - your assumption isn't holding up - and then refuse to compile your code so you can fix it.

### problem: What's the null doing there?

Your RANKS starts with null, and yet you create `new Card(0,1);` which is [A] unreadable, and [B] means you now have a null rank. There's no need for that null. Also, if you use enums and types, it can become the more readable: `new Card(Rank.ACE, Suit.DIAMONDS);`.

### The printing doesn't work

You've put a method in a method (the `printDeck` method is inside the `main` method). Java does not (currently) support this. Move the method such that it is a sibling.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not compile as is. The printDeck() method is currently inside of the definition of the main() method and needs to be moved outside. After moving the method it runs as expected. Here is the modified Jack class:

```
public class Jack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Card small = new Card(0,1); // creates the small object
        Card card = new Card(11,1); // cretes the card object
        System.out.println(small); // prints the small class
        System.out.println(card); // prints the card class
        System.out.println(small.equals(card)); // compares small with cards

        Card[] cards = new Card[52];

        int index = 0; // to keep track
        for (int suit = 0; suit <= 3; suit++) { // outer loop
            for (int rank = 1; rank <= 13; rank++) { // inner loop
                cards[index] = new Card(rank, suit);
                index++;
            }
        }
       printDeck(cards);
    }

    public static void printDeck(Card[] cards) {
        for (Card card : cards) {
            System.out.println(card);
        }
    }
}
```

And the resulting output:

```
null of Diamonds
Jack of Diamonds
false
Ace of Clubs
2 of Clubs
3 of Clubs
4 of Clubs
5 of Clubs
6 of Clubs
7 of Clubs
8 of Clubs
9 of Clubs
10 of Clubs
Jack of Clubs
Queen of Clubs
King of Clubs
Ace of Diamonds
2 of Diamonds
3 of Diamonds
4 of Diamonds
5 of Diamonds
6 of Diamonds
7 of Diamonds
8 of Diamonds
9 of Diamonds
10 of Diamonds
Jack of Diamonds
Queen of Diamonds
King of Diamonds
Ace of Hearts
2 of Hearts
3 of Hearts
4 of Hearts
5 of Hearts
6 of Hearts
7 of Hearts
8 of Hearts
9 of Hearts
10 of Hearts
Jack of Hearts
Queen of Hearts
King of Hearts
Ace of Spades
2 of Spades
3 of Spades
4 of Spades
5 of Spades
6 of Spades
7 of Spades
8 of Spades
9 of Spades
10 of Spades
Jack of Spades
Queen of Spades
King of Spades
```